# VS2010 Setup Project Freezes on 'Select Installation Folder'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I have a pretty basic c# winforms project that has an associated setup project. It has one custom dialog (Textboxes (A)). When I run the installer, it freezes when I click `Next` to go to the `Select Installation Folder` dialog. Then after several minutes, it unfreezes. When I finally click `Install`, the window disappears but `msiexec.exe` is still running in the background (two of them actually).

Could someone please tell me what the heck is going wrong?

EDIT: Here's the msiexec log: http://www.mediafire.com/?jqmmimwjgni

Comment: Is there any of the folders mapped in Explorer currently offline? This could be a timeout issue while the folder selection dialog is trying to get all drives/shares.

Comment: Here's the thing: I don't even get a changes to "Browse for a folder". It's when I click NEXT and then it freezes...

Comment: Best to create a log file of your installation: Call `msiexec /i mysetup.msi /l*vx log.txt` on the console and check what is being logged when you press next. It might be an installer action, e.g. a file system or Registry search.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can make the setup hang just by adding another custom textbox to visible. I did a DIFF on an old working version and this one and those are the only changes. Also, I looked at the log, and see a lot of DEBUG: Error. See my edit above.

Comment: What is the text box doing? How is its value retrieved and what property/action is triggered?

Comment: It's for the Textboxes (A) dialog. I literally set the `Edit3Label`, `Edit3Property`, `Edit3Visible` and that's it. I don't do anything with the actions.

Comment: Also, when I build the setup project, I'm getting the following errors: `WARNING: The version of the .NET Framework launch condition '.NET Framework 3.5' does not match the selected .NET Framework bootstrapper package. Update the .NET Framework launch condition to match the version of the .NET Framework selected in the Prerequisites Dialog Box.
WARNING: Could not find prerequisite '.NET Framework 3.5' in path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem does not seem to be the length of the name, but the fact that the name DATABASE is used as an internal MSI property containing the full filename of the installer file<sup>1</sup>.

If you bind your edit field to that property the value of this property will be overwritten with whatever the edit field contains.

MSI doesn't like that. Unfortunately, I could not find any place where it is documented that **the name DATABASE is reserved** (The built-in MSI properties are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28VS.85%29.aspx)). So I wouldn't say this is a bug in MSI, but bad documentation/developer usability (as it is unfortunately too often the case with Windows Installer).

In your log file you will find the following entries:

> MSI (c) (64:1C) [19:30:12:339]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying DATABASE property. Its current value is 'd:\ ... mysetup.msi'. Its new value: 'ProgressNotes'.

And later on when the installer is hanging:

> MSI (c) (64:68) [19:30:41:701]: Note: 1: 1314 2: ProgressNotes

Here should probably appear the full path to your MSI file...

Solution: Use any other name that is not reserved.

<sup>1<sub>You can easily see this if you set Edit1Property to 'DBProperty' and Edit1Value to '[DATABASE]' (without the single quotes).</sub></sup>

Comment: Yup you're right. mrdivo on Connect pointed this out earlier today and and then I had a "D'OH!" moment where I realized I didn't try anything *other than* 'DATABASE' (I was so concerned with setting this name heh). I'm marking this as the answer because if others find this I want them to read it. Thanks for all your help 0xA3 - what a nasty bug!

Answer (score 1):

I found it! I'm pretty sure this is a bug of some sort with the Setup project (can someone else confirm this?).

**EDIT**: See [0xA3's answer for the *real* reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232509/vs2010-setup-project-freezes-on-select-installation-folder/3242010#3242010) as to why this fails.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add `Textboxes (A)`.
2. Add a set one of the `Edit1Property`, `Edit2Property` etc to `DATABASE` <strike>something *GREATER* than **7 characters**</strike>.
3. Rebuild and install the project (it should hang on the `Select Installation Folder` screen).

Hope this helps someone.

PS - Worst bug *ever* to track down :)

A bug report [has been logged](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574571/setup-textboxes-a-textbox-edit1property-length-hangs-installer) with Microsoft.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but I couldn't see any attachment on the Connect issue. Are you sure it is uploaded?

Comment: Yeah it *is* attached... but it was only for Microsoft's eyes. The reason for that was because the project had my personal name in it and didn't really want that to be available for download. Did you try following the updated steps? If you'd like, I could send you the project.